# macOS Preview: Bug in PDF highlights that displays an additional offset highlight

Tags: pdf, preview, macos, highlights

I update from *OSX El Capitan* to *macOS Sierra* yesterday. Now when I open PDFs containing highlights there are 'double highlights', ie. the original highlight and an additional highlight which is offset slightly. This only happens for some highlights.

See example in picture below. This page should contain 4 highlights (the title of the figure, the p1 and p2 in lower graph, and part of the third last paragraph), but 7 highlights are displayed. Only the last three highlights have "doppelgängers". These additional highlights are offset (down and to the left).

[image: Example of double highlight in macOS Sierra Preview app]

Update: Quick Look displays the highlights correctly. See screenshot below.
[image]

Any suggestions how to fix this?

Comment: Did you try reporting a bug to Apple? https://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: Or try contacting them for help at https://getsupport.apple.com

Comment: I would guess it has something to do with the way the PDF was originally created, and the differences between the plugin that Quick Look uses to generate the preview, and the PDF engine that Preview uses to display the full PDF.

Comment: Apple bugreport: _"Engineering has determined that your bug report (28423222) is a duplicate of another issue (27898257) and will be closed."_ They furthermore write that _"Developer has visibility that this is a duplicate via RadarWeb ... Added Duplicate resolution to ADC Notes ..."_.

Comment: I got ahold of a version 8.1 of the Preview.app from OSX El Capitan. But I am not allowed to open it on macOS Sierra. I can only open the Preview.app that is preinstalled with Sierra [Version 9.0 (909)].

Comment: I'm also experiencing problems with highlighting pdfs in Preview on macOS Sierra. - Disappearing highlights, especially when scrolling. - Duplicate or overlaying highlights. - Removing some highlights won't work. The bug report seems pretty dead. Anyone solutions to this unwanted behavior?

Comment: The bug has been fixed with macOS Sierra version 10.12.1 (I can't add as answer.)

Comment: @bonna It doesn't seem to be fixed on High Sierra for me.

Comment: @spacetyper I've not experienced the problem since 10.12.1. I am not sure why you still experience this problem. Is it a particular PDF file giving you problems or is it a general problem?